# bootstrap active tab in tabs pane hides on focus of input type text area in tablet

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, tablet

bootstrap active tab in tabs pane hides on focus of input type text area in tablet.

we are trying to make our website working on a tablet. Our current focus is google nexus 7. 
In a page, we are using bootstrap tab pane with 6 tabs. on one of the tab, there is a text area. When user try to input in this text area, it vanish in a while. Although same code is working on my pc and simulator (of chrome). seeking your advise.

Comment: can you show us some code? And what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: i had resolve the issue. there was a problem in my javascript.